# Which service has a lower response time? SQS vs DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

Well, I have built a serverless application a time ago by using AWS Lambda. My current application flow is as follows:

`API Gateway (1) → Lambda Function (2) → SQS (3) → Lambda Function (4) → DynamoDB (5)`

Now, there are some considerations:

1. The client is going to send a request to my API (1).
2. There's a lambda function (2) attached to the API event, so it's going to receive the API request and process it.
3. Now, here is where the question enters. After processing the request, the result of this processing MUST be inserted at the DynamoDB (5). Currently, I send it to SQS (3) and return the response of the HTTP request sent by the client.
4. Although the request is finished and responded, the SQS (3) messages are going to be event-pulled by another lambda function (4), that is going to insert the processed message on DynamoDB (5).

When I first prototyped this flow I had a presumption: that sending a message to SQS was faster than inserting it on DynamoDB. However, I never did a real benchmark nor something like this, so my presumption was merely arbitrary.

**The question is, finally:** *which one of the actions is faster? Sending the processed request do SQS or directly to DynamoDB?*

Consider that, in both cases, it's going to be executed from within a lambda function (2), so, teorically, as it's in the same context as AWS itself, it won't have the same response time than requesting it from other machine.

If the answer for this question is:

- Inserting directly on DynamoDB is faster
- Inserting directly on DynamoDB is not faster but the difference is negligible

I may remove both SQS (3) and the second lambda function (4), resulting in a simpler and more direct flow.

However, if there's greater response times by sending first to SQS, I may keep this flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking if SQS is cheaper than DynamoDB, but in your flow you're using both...it will of course be cheaper to just do `API Gateway (1) → Lambda Function (2) → DynamoDB (3)`.

Performance wise, DynamoDB is known to be fast for small, frequent writes, so I wouldn't worry much about that.

The difference between SQS and DynamoDB response time should be very similar, unless your DynamoDB capacity isn't provisioned properly in which case you could have issues with throttles. If provisioned capacity isn't a concern for you, then I suggest testing both SQS and DynamoDB with timers inside your Lambda function (or using AWS x-ray) and decide whether or not the performance difference is worth the cost of adding an SQS and an extra Lambda function

Comment: Yes, I'm using both because the request returns at the first Lambda function, so if SQS has lower response times it will be faster to use it and then send to DynamoDB on the background.

Comment: Edited answer .

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the connection open between invocations I've seen DynamoDB response times below 10ms. I don't have data on SQS latency.

Regarding cost, you are basically doubling your lambda cost, and adding whatever SQS costs you. SQS costs about 33% more than DynamoDB if you are using on-demand writes.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Deiv's and cementblocks responses.

Let me share the following additional perspectives to help you evolve your proposed design.

If you need to strictly abide by async processing, i.e., decouple request processing from response, then stick with your SQS based solution.

If the request processing latency is consistent and acceptable for the consumers of the API endpoint, then I'd recommend the solution that Diev recommended to process request, persist to DynamoDB and return response to client. As bonus, you will have a lower AWS bill (as pointed out above).

DynamoDB is designed to offer "consistent" P99 (i.e., 99th percentile) latency of < 10 ms for single item reads and < 20 ms for single item writes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually don't need, necessarily, to process the request in the background. I just want to return the request as soon as possible. This is why I made this question. Apparently, DynamoDB is fast enough to be used directly, so I'm going to change my design to this simpler and cheaper approach.